# Foundation for Email valign="middle" not working

Tags: zurb-foundation, html-email

I'm using a fresh installation of Foundation for Email, and have the following test set up:

```
<container>

  <wrapper>
    <row>
      <columns large="5" valign="middle">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/690x173" alt="Company Logo">
      </columns>
      <columns large="7" valign="middle">
        <h4 style="margin-bottom: 0;" class="text-right small-text-center">Thanks for your order!</h1>
      </columns>
    </row>
  </wrapper>

</container>
```

I expected the logo and the title to be vertically centered in their container. However, as you can see in the screenshot, there is extra white space at the bottom:

[image]

Even the [example in the documentation](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/alignment.html#vertical-alignment) seems to be working incorrectly. The items are not vertically aligned in the center of their container.

What am I missing here? Why doesn't the `valign` attribute function as the documentation suggests?

Comment: `valign` is a `table` and `td` level element. It's will not work on just any section

Comment: The elements has to be a `table` element for the vertical align to work.

Comment: @scoopzilla this question is specific to Foundation for Emails. `valign` is a supported attribute. See the documentation link in my question and look at the 'INKY' markup.

Comment: Then I do not know.

Comment: You didn't post your html code, so it's hard to tell what might be causing an influence. You should check to see if there's a `margin-bottom: 10px;` adding the space or a `valign="top"` adding to the code.

Answer (score 3):

The `_normalize.scss` file applies `vertical-align: top;` to table, tr, td and th tags. This messes with the vertical alignment.

For this reason, you will need to add `vertical-align: middle;` to the tag as well:

```
<wrapper>
  <row style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <columns large="5" valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle;">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/690x173" alt="Company Logo">
    </columns>
    <columns large="7" valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle;">
      <h4 class="text-right small-text-center">Thanks for your order!</h1>
    </columns>
  </row>
</wrapper>
```

Padding and margins can influence the visual end result quite significantly too, but that's actually a separate issue from the vertical alignment of content within table cells.

Answer (score 2):

I've not tested how well this fix will work in different devices/platforms however you can apply the below to your columns to remove the extra space in your row.

```
  <wrapper>
      <row style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <columns large="5" valign="middle" style="padding-bottom: 0;">
          <img src="https://placehold.it/690x173" alt="Company Logo">
        </columns>
        <columns large="7" valign="middle" style="padding-bottom: 0;">
          <h4 style="margin: 0" class="text-right small-text-center">Thanks for your order!</h1>
        </columns>
      </row>
    </wrapper>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! CSS is finicky stuff, especially with HTML emails. Removing the bottom padding worked like a charm.