# Foundation for Email: Vertical-Align Not Working on Mobile

Tags: html, css, email, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm attempting to vertically align a headline and byline next to an image. The meta text should appear in the middle of the image height. It works great on desktop, but mobile refuses to work. I've attempted to use valign as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082604/foundation-for-email-valign-middle-not-working), but it didn't work. It bumps the text to another row on mobile.

```html
  <row>
    <columns large="1" small="1" class="no-padding"></columns>
    <columns large="7" small="10" class="no-padding little-story">
      <row>
          <columns small="6" large="7">
            <img class="small-float-left" src="https://placehold.it/232x181?text=image" alt="" mc:edit="little_img_three">
          </columns>
          <columns small="6" large="5" class="meta">
            <h6 class="hed" mc:edit="hed_three"><a href="#">Headline</a></h6>
            <div class="subhed" mc:edit="subhed_three">by Person Person</div>
          </columns>
      </row>
      <p mc:edit="little_story_three">Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy</p>
    </columns>
    <columns large="1" small="1" class="no-padding"></columns>
  </row>
```

```css
.little-story {
  .meta {
    vertical-align: middle;
    .hed {
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      margin-left: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .hed a {
      font-family: $sans-serif-fonts;
    }
    .subhed {
      color: #222;
      margin-left: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's what it looks like on Desktop:

[image]

and here's what it looks like on Mobile:

[image]

I tried hard coding a min-height/height/max-height on the `.meta` container, but even that didn't work: the two child components still stick to the top.

I also tried hardcoding the vertical align on the row, as well as the columns, but can't seem to crack the code. Any help would be wholeheartedly appreciated.

Comment: Try `.meta { margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto; }` ?

Comment: I don't believe `Auto` margins work with email HTML/Foundation. I just tried it for good measure and no joy.

Comment: Which mobile email client are you using?

Comment: Also, have you tried putting the `vertical-align` as an inline tag? I know a lot of email clients only look at inline tags (or at least used to).

Comment: I tried adding vertical-align as an inline tag to each individual element, but no luck. I'm using Gmail as a mobile client primarily, but I'm also using the mobile view with Chrome dev tools.

Comment: Ah, have you tried an inline tag of `valign="middle"` ?

Comment: Putting an inline tag of `valign="middle"` on the columns holding the image did the trick. I guess it's because it's the first set of columns. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I think `valign` is essential for Gmail, as I read somewhere. Maybe keep some other inline `vertical-align` styling for the other touchy email clients :P. But, you're welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution, thanks to [@EGC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11700321/egc):

```html
  <row>
     <columns large="1" small="1" class="no-padding"></columns>
     <columns large="7" small="10" class="no-padding little-story">
       <row>
           <columns small="6" large="7" valign="middle">
             <img class="small-float-left" src="https://placehold.it/232x181?text=image" alt="" mc:edit="little_img_three">
           </columns>
           <columns small="6" large="5" class="meta">
             <h6 class="hed" mc:edit="hed_three"><a href="#">Headline</a></h6>
             <div class="subhed" mc:edit="subhed_three">by Person Person</div>
           </columns>
       </row>
       <p mc:edit="little_story_three">Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy Copy</p>
     </columns>
     <columns large="1" small="1" class="no-padding"></columns>
   </row>
```